# Calculation of Quantity * Amount for Dynamically generate fields through Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not able to get row-wise live calculation result in jquery for dynamically related fields.

1st row is fixed where I'm getting the right result but for the rest of the dynamically generated fields, the result is not correct.

The calculations include Quantity * Amount = Total row-wise.

for reference follow below link

https://jsfiddle.net/0d210279/4/

**or below code.**

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="form-group">
    <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control qty" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" placeholder="Enter your amount" class="form-control amount" /></td>
                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
        </div>
        <div>total <lable id='total'></lable></div>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- JS -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //adding field
    var i=1;
    $('#add').click(function(){
        i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="Enter your qty" class="form-control qty" /></td><td><input type="text" name="amount[]" placeholder="Enter your amount" class="form-control amount" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
        //removing button
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
    });

/*
$(document).on('keyup', '.qty', function(){
        //getting sub total
    var sum =0;
    $(".qty").each(function(){
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $("#total").text(sum); //changed val() to text()
});

*/  
    $(document).on('keyup', '.amount', function(){
        //getting sub total
    //var sum =0;
    qty = Number($(".qty").val());
    //alert(qty);
    amount = Number($(".amount").val());
    //alert(amount);
    sum = qty * amount;
    $("#total").val(sum); //changed val() to text()
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
//Removing and generating total 
        var total = $(".total").val();
            var sum = 0;
            $(".qty").each(function(){
                sum += Number($(this).val());
            });
            total = $("#total").val();
            var New_total = sum-total; 
            $("#total").text(New_total);

});



    $('#submit').click(function(){      
        $.ajax({
            url:"name.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                $('#add_name')[0].reset();
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, from looking at your fiddle, it seems that you have an id logical error, since all generated "total" input fields will have the same id (#total). What you need to do is have an increment counter that you can attach to the id as you generate the input field. That way, you always make sure that the id remains unique.

The way I'd go about doing this is looking at how many elements have x name, count the total of that, and add +1 as the incrementation to attach to the generated fields id. In order to fetch that, you could use this:

```
var lastField=$('input[name^="total"]').last().attr('id');

if(lastField)
{
    var count=lastField.replace(/\D/g,'');
}
else
{
    var count=$('input[name^="total"]').length;
}
```

This will give you the count that you can use to attach to your id. You can add this to your button where you create fields and attach the count variable to your "total" id.

I would also recommend that you make a call to a calculation function as onkeyup in the price field. Right now you have to change the quantity in order to get the total price to display.

If I were you, I'd use this way of making id's unique on every element you create with your button. This way you will never run into id errors as you have now. It will also make it easier to target different element values for calculations etc, since you could parse the id as a parameter in a function attached to the generated fields. That way you always have a method to handle specific requests directly related to "that specific" section/element etc.